# How to add new row of data when id is auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5 framework. I don't have enough knowledge.
I have a User model and user table in migrations.

```
   //model
   class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
   {
     use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

     protected $fillable = [
       'name',
       'cnic',
       'age',
       ];
   }


     //migration up function
     public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');           
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('cnic');
        $table->string('age')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
     });
```

I have written an action in controller for adding a new row in the table by accessing id, name and cnic which is passed through Request parameter. Here I haven't given age because I don't need it in every record and it is nullable.
I have updated this record using id.

```
   public function update(Request $request)
    {
      $user = User::findorFail($request->id);
      $user->update(array('name' => $request->name));
      $user->update(array('cnic' => $request->cnic));
      $user->save();
    }
```

But I don't want to do this. I want to add a new row only with given name and cnic because id is auto increment.
Thank You!

Comment: If your using resource controllers, you should have a store method. That's where you create a new record. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Here's a guide, which you can follow and adapt to your needs. You could have foudn this easily with a google searhc\

Comment: *"I have written an action in controller for adding a new row in the table by accessing id, name and cnic which is passed through Request parameter"* to straighten the issue, you **could** insert new row(s) without specifying the ID, on controller side @AnthonyThompson is right. On the model side, you could use `$user = User::create(['name' => $request->name, 'cnic' => $request->cnic])` then call `$user->save()`. edit, if you're interested in [whatever function available in Laravel's model](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

Comment: Thank You @BagusTesa and Antony Thompson

Comment: if the update function return $user; and I want this returned user in an android application from where I called this update action. How can it possible for me to do this. @BagusTesa

Comment: well, you could literally `return $user->toJson();` if you wish, Laravel model implements [toJson()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_toJson) function to make serialization easier or return it in plain as an array.

Comment: Okay, I have to write return $user->toJson(); at the end of this action. but from where I called it was a post function. How that will get data is the form of Json ? @BagusTesa

Comment: on most sites if you submit a post to a web, it will return a page that tells you the information you pass to them is accepted right? basically in Laravel, it doesn't matter what is the method being used. You could always return a response, [try asking around in this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120609/laravel) it is a no go to discuss non-related topics on the comment. Btw, Laravel had [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html) using this response will set the header and jsonify the response automagically. Good coding!

Comment: Ok, Thank you @BagusTesa